# What is the purpose of using JSON.stringify()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using `JSON.stringify` in my react redux application. What's the purpose of `JSON.stringify` in the following context? Even without `JSON.stringify` it works, but yet I've been advised to use `JSON.stringify`.

```
if (JSON.stringify(earlyBird.eBird) !== JSON.stringify(prevProps.earlyBird.eBird)) {
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `props.earlyBird.eBird`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first

`JSON.stringify` converts objects into strings.

Now if you two objects

Like

```
const obj1 = {
   a: 10
}

const obj2 = {
   a: 10
}
```

Now you want to compare them

```
 obj1 === obj2; // returns false
```

But

```
JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2); // returns true
```

Now why your code works

because you are comparing same object

Answer (score 0):

It is used to turn javascript objects into their JSON string equivalent i.e.

```
typeof(JSON.stringify(['Hello'])); //string
typeof(['Hello']); //object
```

Comment: Not only arrays. Infact objects.

Answer (score 0):

In very simple words Stringify converts objects to strings. Your code works because ultimately it's the same thing you are comparing in the if condition. Refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

it is used to convert the JSON objects to strings ..

Answer (score 0):

This is, because how js comparison works [Comparisor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

> - Two distinct objects are never equal for either strict or abstract comparisons.
> - Two strings are strictly equal when they have the same sequence of characters, same length, and same characters in corresponding positions.

In the example below you can see that objects with same attributes will not return true, however converting them to strings does the trick. However, have in mind that order matters and in case attributes are not in the same order equality will not work as expected.

```js
console.log({ x: 5, y:6 } === { x:5, y:6 });
console.log(JSON.stringify({ x: 5, y: 6 }) === JSON.stringify({ x: 5, y: 6 }));
console.log(JSON.stringify({ y: 6, x: 5 }) === JSON.stringify({ x: 5, y: 6 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually not recommended because of the fact, JavaScript doesn’t guarantee the order of the keys. Example
[image]

Instead use:

Deep’s [Equal.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-equal)

Lodash’s [isEqual.](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual)

Fast’s [Equals.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-equals)

For details refer to [why-you-shouldnt-use-json-stringify](https://medium.com/better-programming/why-you-shouldnt-use-json-stringify-to-compare-objects-in-javascript-c9a16b7331e)

Answer (score 0):

If your `prevProps.earlyBird.eBird` is a string, `JSON.stringify` is absolutely not needed. However, if it's an object, then to compare two objects in JavaScript, you need to `stringify` them first. Since you said without `JSON.stringify` it's working, that just points to the fact that the both are strings and, hence `JSON.stringify` is not needed here.